# Setup data for dynamic topic modelling

Tags: python, text-mining, gensim, topic-modeling, pubmed

I'm trying to learn dynamic topic modeling(to capture the semantic changes in the words) from data scrapped from PUBMED. I was able to get the data in the form of xml and was able to extract the "abstract" text and the date information off of it and saved that in the csv format. (But this is just a part of the data.)

Format obtained

Year|month|day|abstractText

I'm planning on using gensim lda for my model

I've never really done topic modeling before and need your help with guiding me through this process one step at a time.

Questions:

1. Is csv a preferred format to feed into gensim lda?
2. for dynamic modeling, how should the time aspect of the data be captured and used in the model?
3. is there a better way to organize the data than in csv files?
4. Should i use the bodytext instead of the abstract for this?

Hope I learn a lot from this. Thanks in advance.